# Want to convert a double to timestamp to hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: powershell

I want to know kernel mode time and user mode time of a process
I am running the below command.

```
$P = Get-WmiObject win32_process -ComputerName XXXXX |Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "XXXX.exe"}

$P.KernelModeTime
28410156250
```

Now I want to convert this KernelModeTime in Hours, minutes. I tried below. but showing error.

```
$t = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 28403125000
```

> New-TimeSpan : Cannot bind parameter 'Seconds'. Cannot convert value
>   "28403125000" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too
>   large or too small for an Int32."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the time to a `timespan`:

```
[timespan]28410156250
```

**Output:**

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 47
Seconds           : 21
Milliseconds      : 15
Ticks             : 28410156250
TotalDays         : 0,0328821252893519
TotalHours        : 0,789171006944444
TotalMinutes      : 47,3502604166667
TotalSeconds      : 2841,015625
TotalMilliseconds : 2841015,625
```